# UI router gives me a blank page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I decided to try out the Ionic framework once again, and I directly walk into an error. When I try to create a route for my app, it returns to me a blank page.

The code I'm running is pretty straight forward:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('app.login', {
    url: "/app/login",
    templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
});
```

The controller assigned to this is just an empty controller, nothing interesting there. Also, I have checked a dozen times that `/pages/login.html` exists, and it does.

How can it be something so simple gives me such a headache?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked the file permission for login.html ?

Comment: Open chrome dev tools and check what happens when router requests `pages/login.html`

Comment: @notgiorgi Nothing happens, no errors. I tried setting the router to a file that doesn't exist, then I get a 404. But Nothing on `login.html`

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik It's on "read only" for all users.

Comment: Does it even request? Try opening dev tools, then right click reload and `Empty cache and hard reload`. Maybe login.html was cached when it was empty.

Comment: @notgiorgi Doesn't work either, to my knowledge it requests though

Comment: well you should change it to read and write , sudo chmod -R 777 /youfile

Comment: @WesleyPeeters if it *does* request, what is the response? status code? You can take a screenshot of requests